Can I use a Joomla website to access non- Joomla apps and services?
I am in the process of learning Joomla I wish to develop a Joomla website, but I need to be able to:

have Joomla navigation links and forms access a REST API served by a Spring Boot service

interface with a React or Angular- based SPA

Use Spring Security for authenticating/authorizing users of a Joomla website


Is it possible for a Joomla site to work with non- Joomla apps and services? If it is, how would one do this?
